# OneSignal (2.0.7) - Can't subscribe pushToken

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, onesignal

I just updated to the latest SDK (2.0.7) of OneSignal.

This is my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method:

```
OneSignal.initWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions, appId: "my-onesignal-id….", handleNotificationAction: nil, settings: [kOSSettingsKeyInAppAlerts: false, kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt: false])
```

And this is how I promt the user to register for push notifications:

```
func registerAtOneSignal() {
OneSignal.registerForPushNotifications()

OneSignal.sendTags([
            "user_id": "1",
            "gender": "MALE",
            "birthdate": "1990-01-13"
            ])

       OneSignal.setSubscription(true)

        OneSignal.IdsAvailable({ (userId, pushToken) in
            NSLog("UserId:%@", userId)
            if (pushToken != nil) {
                NSLog("pushToken:%@", pushToken)
            }
        })
}
```

My problems

1. In the IdsAvailable-method I can always see the userId but the pushToken always returns nil? I even tried the didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken-method at the same time to see if I had problems to generate a token. As it turns out that’s not the problem. I can’t just send the token to OneSignal with the registerForPushNotifications-method.
2. I’m guessing that the user is not getting updated in the dashboard. Because I cant seem to find the user. However I can get the tags when I run this method:

   OneSignal.getTags({ (tags) in
               NSLog("%@", tags)
           })

Thanks.

Comment: Did you enable the push notification capability and the remote notifications background mode on your app target? If so, is the OS requesting notification permissions from the user?

Comment: Yes, both of them has been enabled. And the question for notification permission pops up when i call the OneSignal.registerForPushNotifications()- method. Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you find an solution for this, I am having the same issue :(

Comment: No, unfortunately not. Please post if you find a solution.

Comment: This guy solved the problem!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39023388/onesignal-ios-issue-no-push-token-with-sdk-2-0-7/39474594#39474594